# Loop into an array of objects and access to properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I checked other questions to solve this but I can not figure it out how to solve it in my case: I want to loop through all the items of an array of objects and access to an specific property.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
     var x = myArray[i].property;
     console.log(x);
 }
```

My data array structure:

```
var myArray = [ 
    firstObject: {
        title:"first",
        content:"lorem ipsum"
    },
    secondObject: {
        title:"second",
        content:"lorem ipsum"
    },
    thirdObject: {
        title:"third",
        content:"lorem ipsum"
    }
]
```

Inspecting the console output to be a list of each instance of the object in myArray, but it only retrieves the first object from it. So, how can I access properly to these values? Thanks

Comment: Check your variable names...You are using `i` but increasing `j`.

Comment: oh well, that's sample code not my actual code... so thanks, i'm going to change it but that's not the problem!

Comment: Show your source array and from that ask us what you want to do

Comment: @ohmmho yes it is the problem, you are constantly accessing `myArray[0]` because `i` is always 0

Comment: @Charmander the problem is that with this code I'm getting only the first item from the array.

Comment: @ohmmho it's already answered. you need a recursive function. http://stackoverflow.com/q/15690706/2777098

Comment: Provide your array data with its structure.

Comment: @AliKhanusiya i updated the question with it.

Comment: sorry if the question is uncompleted and the code is poor, i'm newbie but any advices are really welcome! :)

Comment: Kindly tell me your desire output.

Comment: @AliKhanusiya I would like to get ["first", "second", "third"] but with this code right now I'm only getting ["first"].  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var myArray =
[
    {
        title: "first",
        content: "lorem ipsum"
    },
    {
        title: "second",
        content: "lorem ipsum"
    },
    {
        title: "third",
        content: "lorem ipsum"
    }
];
var arrExpectedData = [];
myArray.forEach(function (objSingle) {
    arrExpectedData.push(objSingle.title);
});
console.log(arrExpectedData);
```

Comment: hey, yes! this works :D thank you very much! I mark it as correct.
however, can you explain me the difference between the for and the forEach in this particular case? how it would be if we had on level more? 

I mean, imagine that the title structure instead an string is another object, like this: 
`title:{  date: "2016", category:"production" }`

Thanks!