# JS - How to get value from object by key

Tags: javascript

I have an object called `data` like this:

```
var data = {
  operators: {
    operator1: {
      top: 20,
      left: 20,
      properties: {
        title: 'Operator 1',
        inputs: {},
        outputs: {
          output_1: {
            label: 'Output 1',
          },
          output_2: {
            label: 'Output 2',
          }
        }
      }
    },
    operator2: {
      top: 80,
      left: 300,
      properties: {
        title: 'Operator 2',
        inputs: {
          input_1: {
            label: 'Input 1',
          },
          input_2: {
            label: 'Input 2',
          },
          input_3: {
            label: 'Input 3',
          },
        },
        outputs: {}
      }
    },
  },
};
```

How to get a value from `data` by a key.

```
function myFunction(data, key) {
  //Find in data with key, and return value.
}
```

Result: `var result = myFunction(data,'output_1')` = `Output 1` (get by Title).

Comment: _"value like Json data"_ - it's an _object_. ;)

Comment: Check the answer to this question: [Search recursively for value in object by property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603913/search-recursively-for-value-in-object-by-property-name)

Comment: What do you mean by `get by Title` when you are passing a key to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach and exit early if found.

The function `getValue` returns an object if found, otherwise it returnes false.

To get the value, you could take the property `value`.

```js
function getValue(object, key) {
    var result;
    return Object.keys(object).some(function (k) {
        if (k === key) {
            result = { value: object[k] };
            return true;
        }
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object' && (result = getValue(object[k], key))) {
            return true;
        }
    }) && result;    
}

var data = { operators: { operator1: { top: 20, left: 20, properties: { title: 'Operator 1', inputs: {}, outputs: { output_1: { label: 'Output 1' }, output_2: { label: 'Output 2' } } } }, operator2: { top: 80, left: 300, properties: { title: 'Operator 2', inputs: { input_1: { label: 'Input 1' }, input_2: { label: 'Input 2' }, input_3: { label: 'Input 3', foo: null } }, outputs: {} } } } };

console.log(getValue(data, 'output_1').value); // { label: 'Output 1' }
console.log(getValue(data, 'foo').value);      // null
console.log(getValue(data, 'bar'));            // false
console.log(getValue(data, 'bar').value);      // undefined
```

Comment: Can I get invert result? Ex:  `Output 1` => `output_1` (`Output 1` is unique)

Comment: you mean, you want to search by value? just reverse check for `object[k] === value` and return the key instead of the value.

Comment: That's right !! :D

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution could be:

```
function myFunction(data,key){
  if(data[key]){
    return data[key];
  }else{
    return myFunction(data[key],key);
  }
}
```