# Check if output in the Object of arrays has 'error' and display the message in the 'error'

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nested

Check if output in the Object of arrays (steps) has 'error' and display the message in the 'error' along with the particular id.

I want to display the error if exists in JavaScript.

Here is the JSON,

```
{
  "steps": [
    {
      "start": null,
      "stop": null,
      "status": "PENDING",
      "input": null,
      "output": null,
      "id": "45968631-4b24-4b80-a618-954ec383ce8d"
    },
    {
      "start": "2019-08-23T00:11:27.323325Z",
      "stop": "2019-08-23T00:11:50.581740Z",
      "status": "SUCCESS",
      "input": {
        "url": "https://www.google.com"
      },
      "output": {
        "filepath": "/tmp/filepath"
      },
      "id": "153eec8e-aff0-4566-9dee-bd2235f59886"
    },
    {
      "start": "2019-08-23T00:26:31.377313Z",
      "stop": "2019-08-23T00:26:58.489024Z",
      "status": "SUCCESS",
      "input": null,
      "output": {
        "url": "url"
      },
      "id": "cb2280a8-3b75-4e7b-9052-42a563b4fd9e"
    },
    {
      "start": "2019-08-23T00:41:00.988154Z",
      "stop": "2019-08-23T00:41:04.528278Z",
      "status": "SUCCESS",
      "input": {
        "key": "userKey"
      },
      "output": {
        "error": "ProcessorError"
      },
      "id": "65324ed2-d347-4a35-8fdc-fe11b98d5e70"
    }
  ]
}
```

There are some places, where Output does not have 'error' and some it has null.

Comment: What research have you done or what code have you written to achieve this? It's expected that you have attempted to answer your own question before asking us, otherwise your question is nothing more than a code request. Please edit your question to include your attempts at completing your own request so that we can help you debug.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search recursively for value in object by property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603913/search-recursively-for-value-in-object-by-property-name)

Comment: @TylerRoper , for your question, I had initially thought of this and It was not matching my expectations for output, Yes may be I need to learn more of filter and map. Here is what I tried. 
```checkError(data){
      console.log('ERROR', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
      const vals = data.steps.filter( (ele) =>  {
        const message = '';
        if(ele.output !== null) {
          this.message = ele.output.error;
          console.log('Message', message);
        }
        return message;
      });```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve this with `filter()` and `map()` method.

```js
const obj = {
    "steps": [{
            "start": null,
            "stop": null,
            "status": "PENDING",
            "input": null,
            "output": null,
            "id": "45968631-4b24-4b80-a618-954ec383ce8d"
    }, {
            "start": "2019-08-23T00:11:27.323325Z",
            "stop": "2019-08-23T00:11:50.581740Z",
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "input": {
                    "url": "https://www.google.com"
            },
            "output": {
                    "filepath": "/tmp/filepath"
            },
            "id": "153eec8e-aff0-4566-9dee-bd2235f59886"
    }, {
            "start": "2019-08-23T00:26:31.377313Z",
            "stop": "2019-08-23T00:26:58.489024Z",
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "input": null,
            "output": {
                    "url": "url"
            },
            "id": "cb2280a8-3b75-4e7b-9052-42a563b4fd9e"
    }, {
            "start": "2019-08-23T00:41:00.988154Z",
            "stop": "2019-08-23T00:41:04.528278Z",
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "input": {
                    "key": "userKey"
            },
            "output": {
                    "error": "ProcessorError"
            },
            "id": "65324ed2-d347-4a35-8fdc-fe11b98d5e70"
    }]
}

const result = obj.steps.
filter((r) => {
    return r.output && r.output.error;
}).map((m) => {
    return {
            id: m.id,
            error: m.output.error
    }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you want to do here but this is how you could check for the error in each one and do something accordingly.

```js
let data={"steps":[{"start":null,"stop":null,"status":"PENDING","input":null,"output":null,"id":"45968631-4b24-4b80-a618-954ec383ce8d"},{"start":"2019-08-23T00:11:27.323325Z","stop":"2019-08-23T00:11:50.581740Z","status":"SUCCESS","input":{"url":"https://www.google.com"},"output":{"filepath":"/tmp/filepath"},"id":"153eec8e-aff0-4566-9dee-bd2235f59886"},{"start":"2019-08-23T00:26:31.377313Z","stop":"2019-08-23T00:26:58.489024Z","status":"SUCCESS","input":null,"output":{"url":"url"},"id":"cb2280a8-3b75-4e7b-9052-42a563b4fd9e"},{"start":"2019-08-23T00:41:00.988154Z","stop":"2019-08-23T00:41:04.528278Z","status":"SUCCESS","input":{"key":"userKey"},"output":{"error":"ProcessorError"},"id":"65324ed2-d347-4a35-8fdc-fe11b98d5e70"}]}

data.steps.forEach(item => {
  //  Check for output's existence then an error's existence
  if (!!item.output && !!item.output.error) {
    console.log(item.output.error);
  }
});
```

Comment: if "output.error" is an empty string, this code would say it doesn't exist. Better to use `if ("output" in item && "error" in item.output)`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The prompt said output could be null or error could not exist on the object. I went off that and solved those cases. Though yes, it does not account for empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

save your data in a variable `var data` and apply this sentence

```
data.steps.filter(x=>x.output && x.output.error).map(result=>({id:result.id,errro:result.output.error}))
```

Comment: if "output.error" is an empty string, this code would say it doesn't exist. Better to use `"output" in x && "error" in x.output`.