# Counting object in side array of array object by property javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, count

I have data like:

```
var data = [
  {
    items: [
      {
        id: 123
      },
      {
        id: 234
      },
      {
        id: 123
      }
    ]
  }, {
    items: [
      {
        id: 123
      },
      {
        id: 234
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

so, I want count object deep in array inside of all data by property 'id'.
ex: `data.countObject('id',123) //return 3.`
and my data have about xx.000 item, which solution best?
Thanks for help (sorry for my English)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603913/search-recursively-for-value-in-object-by-property-name to get started.

Comment: Do you want to get number of objects with this id `123`?

Comment: thanks, but my data have about xx.000 item, which solution best

Comment: @brk yes, count quality object have id =123

Comment: The simplest version would be two loops. So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` & `forEach`. Inside the `reduce` callback you can access the `items` array using `curr.items` where `acc` & `curr` are just parameters of the call back function. Then you can use `curr.items.forEach` to get each object inside `items` array

```js
var data = [{
  items: [{
      id: 123
    },
    {
      id: 234
    },
    {
      id: 123
    }
  ]
}, {
  items: [{
      id: 123
    },
    {
      id: 234
    }
  ]
}];

function getCount(id) {

  return data.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    // iterate through item array and check if the id is same as
    // required id. If same then add 1 to the accumulator
    curr.items.forEach(function(item) {
      item.id === id ? acc += 1 : acc += 0;
    })
    return acc;
  }, 0) // 0 is the accumulator, initial value is 0
}

console.log(getCount(123))
```