# Push values from nested objects

Tags: javascript, object

I would like to know the best method for grabbing values from nested objects like this one:

```
var object = {
    1: {
        1: {
        "names": "bob"
        },
        2: {
        "names": "jim"
        }
    }
}
```

What function or loop would I write to push the values “bob” and “Jim” into an array?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use nested loops. The outer loop iterates over the properties of `object`, the inner loop iterates over the properties of `object[i]`.

Comment: Would I nest a loop for every “layer” I am trying to access?

Comment: Yes. If it has arbitrary hierarchical nesting, you'd use a recursive function.

Comment: You’re a life saver. Thank you, Barmar

Comment: Would you have an example of a recursive function for this scenario where I would want [‘bob’, ‘jim’] as a result?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603913/search-recursively-for-value-in-object-by-property-name for how to search for a property recursively. Instead of returning the value, push it onto the result array.

Comment: Again, you rock. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to use nested loops to access the values I wanted; however, it only pushed the last value that met the logic to the array. What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a reason nested loops would only push the last value

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's impossible to tell. Common errors I've seen in the past are assigning rather than pushing, or initializing the variable inside the loop instead of before it.

Comment: You were right. Variable was inside of the loop. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Object.values` + `map`

```
Object.values(object[1]).map(p => p.names)
```

Comment: You're assuming that the top-level object only has one property that's always `object[1]`. That seems unlikely.