# How to use reduce to retrieve values from deep nested array objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a list of all users with the `author.username` property. So that means access posts author, comments author, and commentReplies author. I want an returned array with a list of usernames.

expected output

```
["blankman", "blankman2", "barnowl", "barnowl2", "blankman3"]
```

the wrong output

```
["blankman", "blankman2blankman3", "barnowl2"]
```

This is how im doing it but i think im doing it wrong. as its not dynamic

```js
const arr = [{
  "id": 5,
  "title": "buttercup",
  "postContent": "dsdsfsfsfsfsfs",
  "likedByMe": false,
  "likeCounts": 0,
  "userId": 1,
  "createdAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z",
  "author": {
    "username": "blankman",
    "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN",
    "bio": null
  },
  "Likes": [],
  "Comments": [{
      "id": 46,
      "comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf",
      "gifUrl": "",
      "userId": 1,
      "postId": 5,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "commentReplies": [{
        "id": 18,
        "replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf",
        "userId": 2,
        "commentId": 46,
        "postId": 5,
        "createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
        "author": {
          "username": "barnowl",
          "gravatar": null,
          "bio": null
        }
      }],
      "author": {
        "username": "blankman2",
        "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN",
        "bio": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 47,
      "comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf",
      "gifUrl": "",
      "userId": 1,
      "postId": 5,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "commentReplies": [{
        "id": 18,
        "replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf",
        "userId": 2,
        "commentId": 46,
        "postId": 5,
        "createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
        "author": {
          "username": "barnowl2",
          "gravatar": null,
          "bio": null
        }
      }],
      "author": {
        "username": "blankman3",
        "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN",
        "bio": null
      }
    },

  ],
  "RePosts": [],
  "RepostedByMe": false
}]

const findUsers = arr.reduce((acc, cv) => {
  const users = [
    ...acc,
    cv.author.username, // get first level author.username
    cv.Comments.reduce((acc, cv) => acc.concat(cv.author.username), ""), // get comments author.username 
    cv.Comments.reduce((acc, cv) => cv.commentReplies.reduce((acc, cv) => acc.concat(cv.author.username), ""), "") // get comment replies author.username

  ]
  return users
}, [])
console.log(findUsers)
```

Comment: It sounds like recursion would be useful here

Comment: ohhh, yeah i have to look into that as i never really used recursion. but not sure how to use recursion in a scenario like this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40603913/search-recursively-for-value-in-object-by-property-name for a starting point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this iteratively or recursively:

```js
const arr = [{
  "id": 5,
  "title": "buttercup",
  "postContent": "dsdsfsfsfsfsfs",
  "likedByMe": false,
  "likeCounts": 0,
  "userId": 1,
  "createdAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z",
  "author": {
    "username": "blankman",
    "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN",
    "bio": null
  },
  "Likes": [],
  "Comments": [
    {
      "id": 46,
      "comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf",
      "gifUrl": "",
      "userId": 1,
      "postId": 5,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "commentReplies": [
        {
          "id": 18,
          "replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf",
          "userId": 2,
          "commentId": 46,
          "postId": 5,
          "createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
          "author": {
            "username": "barnowl",
            "gravatar": null,
            "bio": null
          }
        }
      ],
      "author": {
        "username": "blankman2",
        "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN",
        "bio": null
      }
    },
     {
      "id": 47,
      "comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf",
      "gifUrl": "",
      "userId": 1,
      "postId": 5,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "commentReplies": [
        {
          "id": 18,
          "replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf",
          "userId": 2,
          "commentId": 46,
          "postId": 5,
          "createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
          "author": {
            "username": "barnowl2",
            "gravatar": null,
            "bio": null
          }
        }
      ],
      "author": {
        "username": "blankman3",
        "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN",
        "bio": null
      }
    },
    
  ],
  "RePosts": [],
  "RepostedByMe": false
}]

// No recursion
function getUsers(array) {
  return array.flatMap(v => {
    let comments = v.Comments;
    return [v.author.username].concat(comments.flatMap(c => {
      let replies = c.commentReplies;
      return [c.author.username].concat(replies.flatMap(r => {
        return r.author.username;
      }));
    }));
  });
}

// Recursion
function recursGetUsers(array) {
  if (!array) return [];
  return array.flatMap(v => {
    return [v.author.username]
    .concat(recursGetUsers(v.Comments))
    .concat(recursGetUsers(v.commentReplies));
  });
}

console.log(getUsers(arr));

console.log(recursGetUsers(arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use several nested `flatMap` and `map` operations.

```js
const arr = [{ "id": 5, "title": "buttercup", "postContent": "dsdsfsfsfsfsfs", "likedByMe": false, "likeCounts": 0, "userId": 1, "createdAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z", "updatedAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z", "author": { "username": "blankman", "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN", "bio": null }, "Likes": [], "Comments": [{ "id": 46, "comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf", "gifUrl": "", "userId": 1, "postId": 5, "createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z", "updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z", "commentReplies": [{ "id": 18, "replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf", "userId": 2, "commentId": 46, "postId": 5, "createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z", "updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z", "author": { "username": "barnowl", "gravatar": null, "bio": null } }], "author": { "username": "blankman2", "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN", "bio": null } }, { "id": 47, "comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf", "gifUrl": "", "userId": 1, "postId": 5, "createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z", "updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z", "commentReplies": [{ "id": 18, "replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf", "userId": 2, "commentId": 46, "postId": 5, "createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z", "updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z", "author": { "username": "barnowl2", "gravatar": null, "bio": null } }], "author": { "username": "blankman3", "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN", "bio": null } }, ], "RePosts": [], "RepostedByMe": false }];
const res = arr.flatMap(x => [x.author.username].concat(x.Comments.flatMap(y => y.commentReplies.map(z => z.author.username).concat(y.author.username))));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursion by handing over the key of the parent object.

It works with three steps,

1. check if the handed over value is an array and if not return an empty array,
2. check if parent key is `author` and if property `username` exist, then take the value of the `username` property.
3. get the entries of the object and get all usernames with a recursion by handing over the parent key.

```js
const
    getUsernames = (object, parent) => {
        if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return [];
        const temp = [];
        if (parent === 'author' && 'username' in object) temp.push(object.username);
        return [
            ...temp,
            ...Object.entries(object).flatMap(([k, v]) => getUsernames(v, k))
        ];
    },
    data = [{ id: 5, title: "buttercup", postContent: "dsdsfsfsfsfsfs", likedByMe: false, likeCounts: 0, userId: 1, createdAt: "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z", updatedAt: "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z", author: { username: "blankman", gravatar: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN", bio: null }, Likes: [], Comments: [{ id: 46, comment_body: "fsfsfsfsfsf", gifUrl: "", userId: 1, postId: 5, createdAt: "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z", updatedAt: "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z", commentReplies: [{ id: 18, replyBody: "fsfsffsffsffsf", userId: 2, commentId: 46, postId: 5, createdAt: "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z", updatedAt: "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z", author: { username: "barnowl", gravatar: null, bio: null } }], author: { username: "blankman2", gravatar: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN", bio: null } }, { id: 47, comment_body: "fsfsfsfsfsf", gifUrl: "", userId: 1, postId: 5, createdAt: "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z", updatedAt: "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z", commentReplies: [{ id: 18, replyBody: "fsfsffsffsffsf", userId: 2, commentId: 46, postId: 5, createdAt: "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z", updatedAt: "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z", author: { username: "barnowl2", gravatar: null, bio: null } }], author: { username: "blankman3", gravatar: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN", bio: null } }], RePosts: [], RepostedByMe: false }],
    result = getUsernames(data);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you nina this works but this is not that readable. I appreciate the answer, will upvote.

Answer (score 1):

If your schema is settled down, your approach is a solution and almost reaching the goal (though **recursion** is another solution). the problem in your codes is uses `Array.concat` then return `String`. You should return one `[]` same as the most outer reduce.

Check below snippet:

```js
const arr = [{
  "id": 5,
  "title": "buttercup",
  "postContent": "dsdsfsfsfsfsfs",
  "likedByMe": false,
  "likeCounts": 0,
  "userId": 1,
  "createdAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z",
  "updatedAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z",
  "author": {
    "username": "blankman",
    "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN",
    "bio": null
  },
  "Likes": [],
  "Comments": [
    {
      "id": 46,
      "comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf",
      "gifUrl": "",
      "userId": 1,
      "postId": 5,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "commentReplies": [
        {
          "id": 18,
          "replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf",
          "userId": 2,
          "commentId": 46,
          "postId": 5,
          "createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
          "author": {
            "username": "barnowl",
            "gravatar": null,
            "bio": null
          }
        }
      ],
      "author": {
        "username": "blankman2",
        "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN",
        "bio": null
      }
    },
     {
      "id": 47,
      "comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf",
      "gifUrl": "",
      "userId": 1,
      "postId": 5,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "commentReplies": [
        {
          "id": 18,
          "replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf",
          "userId": 2,
          "commentId": 46,
          "postId": 5,
          "createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
          "updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
          "author": {
            "username": "barnowl2",
            "gravatar": null,
            "bio": null
          }
        }
      ],
      "author": {
        "username": "blankman3",
        "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN",
        "bio": null
      }
    },
    
  ],
  "RePosts": [],
  "RepostedByMe": false
}]

const findUsers = arr.reduce((acc, cv) => {
  const users = [
    ...acc,
    cv.author.username, // get first level author.username
    ...cv.Comments.reduce((acc, cv) => [...acc, cv.author.username], []), // get comments author.username 
    ...cv.Comments.reduce((acc, cv) => [...acc, ...cv.commentReplies.reduce((acc, cv) => [...acc, cv.author.username], [])], []) // get comment replies author.username

  ]
  return users
}, [])

console.log(findUsers)
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need a recursive function. With `flatMap` you can ensure that the recursively returned arrays are put together as a single flat array.

Here is a possible implementation that doesn't depend on property names like "Comments" and "commentReplies", but just scans all arrays:

```js
const collect = arr => Array.isArray(arr) ? arr.flatMap(value => 
    [value.author?.username].concat(Object.values(value).flatMap(collect))
).filter(Boolean) : [];

// demo
const arr = [{"id": 5,"title": "buttercup","postContent": "dsdsfsfsfsfsfs","likedByMe": false,"likeCounts": 0,"userId": 1,"createdAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z","updatedAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z","author": {"username": "blankman","gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN","bio": null},"Likes": [],"Comments": [{"id": 46,"comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf","gifUrl": "","userId": 1,"postId": 5,"createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z","updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z","commentReplies": [{"id": 18,"replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf","userId": 2,"commentId": 46,"postId": 5,"createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z","updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z","author": {"username": "barnowl","gravatar": null,"bio": null}}],"author": {"username": "blankman2","gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN","bio": null}},{"id": 47,"comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf","gifUrl": "","userId": 1,"postId": 5,"createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z","updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z","commentReplies": [{"id": 18,"replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf","userId": 2,"commentId": 46,"postId": 5,"createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z","updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z","author": {"username": "barnowl2","gravatar": null,"bio": null}}],"author": {"username": "blankman3","gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN","bio": null}},],"RePosts": [],"RepostedByMe": false}];
console.log(collect(arr));
```

If you find this functional expression syntax confusing, then here is something similar in a more verbose manner:

```js
function collect(arr) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) return [];
    let result = [];
    for (let obj of arr) {
        result.push(obj.author?.username);
        for (let key in obj) {
            result = result.concat(collect(obj[key]));
        }
    }
    return result.filter(Boolean); // exclude null/undefined values
}
// demo
const arr = [{"id": 5,"title": "buttercup","postContent": "dsdsfsfsfsfsfs","likedByMe": false,"likeCounts": 0,"userId": 1,"createdAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z","updatedAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z","author": {"username": "blankman","gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN","bio": null},"Likes": [],"Comments": [{"id": 46,"comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf","gifUrl": "","userId": 1,"postId": 5,"createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z","updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z","commentReplies": [{"id": 18,"replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf","userId": 2,"commentId": 46,"postId": 5,"createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z","updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z","author": {"username": "barnowl","gravatar": null,"bio": null}}],"author": {"username": "blankman2","gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN","bio": null}},{"id": 47,"comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf","gifUrl": "","userId": 1,"postId": 5,"createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z","updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z","commentReplies": [{"id": 18,"replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf","userId": 2,"commentId": 46,"postId": 5,"createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z","updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z","author": {"username": "barnowl2","gravatar": null,"bio": null}}],"author": {"username": "blankman3","gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN","bio": null}},],"RePosts": [],"RepostedByMe": false}];
console.log(collect(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the schema of your object:

- `author.username`
- `Comments[i].author.username`
- `Comments[i].commentReplies[i].author.username`

You asked specifically for a way using `.reduce` so here is one solution using `.reduce` along with lots of destructuring:

```js
const usernames = arr.reduce((names, { author: { username }, Comments }) => {
  names.push(username);
  Comments.forEach(({ author: { username }, commentReplies }) => {
    names.push(username);
    commentReplies.forEach(({ author: { username } }) => names.push(username));
  });
  return names;
}, []);
```

Live example:

```js
'use strict';

const arr = [
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "buttercup",
    "postContent": "dsdsfsfsfsfsfs",
    "likedByMe": false,
    "likeCounts": 0,
    "userId": 1,
    "createdAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-08-17T03:41:16.749Z",
    "author": {
      "username": "blankman",
      "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN",
      "bio": null
    },
    "Likes": [],
    "Comments": [{
      "id": 46,
      "comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf",
      "gifUrl": "",
      "userId": 1,
      "postId": 5,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "commentReplies": [{
        "id": 18,
        "replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf",
        "userId": 2,
        "commentId": 46,
        "postId": 5,
        "createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
        "author": {
          "username": "barnowl",
          "gravatar": null,
          "bio": null
        }
      }],
      "author": {
        "username": "blankman2",
        "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN",
        "bio": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 47,
      "comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf",
      "gifUrl": "",
      "userId": 1,
      "postId": 5,
      "createdAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-08-18T04:46:08.946Z",
      "commentReplies": [{
        "id": 18,
        "replyBody": "fsfsffsffsffsf",
        "userId": 2,
        "commentId": 46,
        "postId": 5,
        "createdAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-21T16:40:47.205Z",
        "author": {
          "username": "barnowl2",
          "gravatar": null,
          "bio": null
        }
      }],
      "author": {
        "username": "blankman3",
        "gravatar": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GiZAw_0UZmt7X0pJFSIv6ELQMd2nN41v0a-eKrN",
        "bio": null
      }
    },
    ],
    "RePosts": [],
    "RepostedByMe": false
  }
];

// author.username
// Comments[i].author.username
// Comments[i].commentReplies[i].author.username

const usernames = arr.reduce((names, { author: { username }, Comments }) => {
  names.push(username);
  Comments.forEach(({ author: { username }, commentReplies }) => {
    names.push(username);
    commentReplies.forEach(({ author: { username } }) => names.push(username));
  });
  return names;
}, []);

console.log(usernames);
// => [ 'blankman', 'blankman2', 'barnowl', 'blankman3', 'barnowl2' ]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,  others have pointed out that recursion would be a better approach opposed to reduce. This answer gives me an idea on how to use reduce to get the values respectively. Thank you for the answer, will give it an upvote.