# How to loop inside a map() loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

The below script outputs

```
================================================
Log entry ID: 1
UUID: 2
Timestamp: 3
--------------------
Log entry ID: 4
UUID: 5
Timestamp: 6
```

which is what I want.

Right now `description` is hard coded, where I would like it to be built using `arr` instead.

My current thinking were to somehow generate the inner array in the `map()` function:

```
[
    `Log entry ID: ${element['_id']}`,
    `UUID: ${element['_source'].uuid}`,
    `Timestamp: ${element['_source']['@timestamp']}\n`,
]
```

but because of the templating, this is not even a valid array with 3 elements, when looking at it on its own. So I am all out of ideas.

**Question**

Somehow I have to loop over the elements in `arr` before it is given to `map()`, I suppose.

Does anyone know how that could be done?

```
const dedent = require('dedent');

const arr = [
  [ 'Log entry ID', '_id' ],
  [ 'UUID', 'uuid' ],
  [ 'Timestamp', '@timestamp' ],
]
;

const docs = [
  {'_id': 1,'_source': {'uuid': 2,'@timestamp': 3}},
  {'_id': 4,'_source': {'uuid': 5,'@timestamp': 6}},
];

const description = dedent`
================================================
${
  docs.map((element) => [
    `Log entry ID: ${element['_id']}`,
    `UUID: ${element['_source'].uuid}`,
    `Timestamp: ${element['_source']['@timestamp']}\n`,
  ].join('\n')).join('--------------------\n')
}
`;

console.log(description);
```

**Update**

I control `arr` so changing it to eg. is possible, or something else

```
const arr = [
  [ 'Log entry ID', '_id' ],
  [ 'UUID', {'_source': 'uuid'} ],
  [ 'Timestamp', {'_source': '@timestamp'} ],
]
;
```

Comment: It's a little bit confusing that the keys you want to access have different depths (_id: 1, uuid:2, etc). Do you control both vars: `arr` and `docs`?

Comment: @JohanDettmar I control `arr`, so it could be structured differently if that makes it easier.

Comment: If you know that the keys will be unique for the entire item of `docs`, regardless of depth, it's sufficient to do a search solely on that key name. Otherwise we would need a unique "key path" to the value of interest.

Comment: @JohanDettmar What if `_source` somehow could be included in the elements of `arr`, so there won't be a need for a search?

Comment: @JohanDettmar I have now updated OP, where I have suggested another way to structure `arr` so hopefully no searching is needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `arr` is in your control perhaps you can specify the path of the key itself.

```js
const arr = [
  ['Log entry ID', '_id'],
  ['UUID', '_source.uuid'],
  ['Timestamp', '_source.@timestamp'],
  ['Description', '_source._desc']
];

const docs = [{
    '_id': 1,
    '_source': {
      'uuid': 2,
      '@timestamp': 3,
      '_desc': 'test 1'
    }
  },
  {
    '_id': 4,
    '_source': {
      'uuid': 5,
      '@timestamp': 6,
      '_desc': 'test 2'
    }
  },
];

const getValue = (object, keys) => keys.split('.').reduce((o, k) => (o || {})[k], object);

console.log(docs.map((element) => arr.map((label) => {
  return `${label[0]}: ${getValue(element, label[1])}`
}).join('\n')).join('\n--------------------\n'))
```

Comment: Can you explain what `getValue()` does? I have never used `reduce()` before so I can't quite figure out what problem `getValue()` solves?

Comment: `getValue` method converts a javascript string in dot notation into an object reference. Basically `_source.uuid` is the key to get uuid from docs, so getValue will iterate into docs object to search `_source.uuid`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the keys of a `docs` array element are all unique, one could traverse the object looking for a matching key.

```js
function findVal(object, key) {
    var value;
    Object.keys(object).some(function(k) {
        if (k === key) {
            value = object[k];
            return true;
        }
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            value = findVal(object[k], key);
            return value !== undefined;
        }
    });
    return value;
}


docs.map((element) =>
arr.map(([item, key]) =>
    `${item}: ${findVal(element, key)}`)
)
```

The `FindVal` is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40604638/704371).

Answer (score 0):

you could create a function to get data from `arr` and put in description

```
/* Simple Hello World in Node.js */

const arr = [
  [ 'Log entry ID', '_id' ],
  [ 'UUID', 'uuid' ],
  [ 'Timestamp', '@timestamp' ],
]
;

const docs = [
  {'_id': 1,'_source': {'uuid': 2,'@timestamp': 3}},
  {'_id': 4,'_source': {'uuid': 5,'@timestamp': 6}},
];
const findInArr=function(value){
    var t = ""
    arr.forEach(item=>{
        if (item.includes(value)) {t = item[0]}
        
    })
    return t
}
const description = dedent`
================================================
 ${
 docs.map((element) => [
    `${findInArr('_id')}: ${element['_id']}`,
    `${findInArr('UUID')}: ${element['_source'].uuid}`,
    `${findInArr('Timestamp')}: ${element['_source']['@timestamp']}\n`,
  ].join('\n')).join('--------------------\n')
}`;

console.log(description);
```