# MarkLogic Get all Nested Field name of Json document using javascript

Tags: javascript, marklogic

I need a recursive function in javascript, which can return me all fieldname (Key Name) of my json document store in MarkLogic. JSON document is very dynamic and have multiple hierarchical elements. So need a function which can traverse through JSON and fetch all fieldname (Keys Name).

One option I thought was to get entire document into MaP object and run Map function to get all keys. But not sure whether MarkLogic allows to capture entire json doucment into Map and one can read fields names.

Thanks in Advance

Got the function to iterate through JSON document to pull Key Name

**Sample JSON**

```
var object = {
    aProperty: {
        aSetting1: 1,
        aSetting2: 2,
        aSetting3: 3,
        aSetting4: 4,
        aSetting5: 5
    },
    bProperty: {
        bSetting1: {
            bPropertySubSetting : true
        },
        bSetting2: "bString"
    },
    cProperty: {
        cSetting: "cString"
    }
}
```

**Solution available at StackOverflow**

[Recursively looping through an object to build a property list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690706/recursively-looping-through-an-object-to-build-a-property-list)

*

```
function iterate(obj, stack) {
        for (var property in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
                    iterate(obj[property], stack + '.' + property);
                } else {
                    console.log(property + "   " + obj[property]);
                    $('#output').append($("<div/>").text(stack + '.' + property))
                }
            }
        }
    }
iterate(object, '')*
```

Comment: what methods you try to make this work, is there any error you facing. first try to implement, if anywhere you stuck, again come here to ask

Comment: It would also help if you could elaborate on the why you need this. There are various ways, but knowing what you are trying to achieve might help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This handy page may help: [MarkLogic - Native JSON](https://developer.marklogic.com/features/json)

The following will extract all property names

```
var json = fn.head(xdmp.unquote('{  foo : "bar", baz : { buz: "boo", chicken : { option1 : "soup", option2 : "salad" } } }'))

json.xpath("//*/name()");
```

Output: `foo baz buz chicken option1 option2`

If, after reviewing the samples on that page you still need assistance, I suggest updating your question with example JSON and desired output (even if it is meant to be dynamic, an example people can copy/paste and work with helps alot)