# Accessing multiple nested objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, square-bracket

I am making a global data storage for my app (Angular JS app - but this is a question about JS, not Angular particularly).

I've set up a `service` that sets the data, gets the data, etc.

It looks like so:

```
angular.module('core').factory('dataService', function(callsService) {
  let properties = {
    globalData: {}
  };

  properties.insertData = function(data) {
    for (let x in data) {
      this.globalData[x] = data[x];
    }
    return;
  }

  properties.getData = function(data) {
    return this.globalData[data];
  }

  return properties;
});
```

Using the service would go like so:

```
dataService.insertData({foo: 'bar'});
dataService.getData('foo'); // 'bar'
```

However it becomes a problem when there is nested data, like so:

```
dataService.insertData({foo: {bar: 'hello world'}});
dataService.getData('foo'); // {bar: 'hello world'}
```

This obviously is how object refernces would work, but how could I pass something like:

```
dataService.getData('foo.bar'); // 'hello world'
```

or

```
dataService.getData('[foo][bar]'); // 'hello world'
```

Going back to my `properties.getData` method, is there a way to recursively (or some other way) access nested objects?

```
properties.getData = function(data) {
  return this.globalData[data]; // needs to be able to get nested objects
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25370536/5535245).

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer:**

I think this recursive one liner will do exactly what you're looking for:

```
properties.getData = (args, data) => args.length ? this.getData(args.slice(1), data ? data[args[0]] : this.globalData[args[0]]) : data ? data : this.globalData
```

Call it with your infinite amount of property-arguments or array indices in an array like so:

```
dataService.getData(['arrayOfData', 2, 'propOnArrElement', 'subProp', 'desiredValue'])
```

**Explanation:**

The "signature" of the function would be something like

`getData(args: Array, data?: any): any`,

which means:

1. It takes an Array as the first argument (containing the trail of properties/indices you wish to traverse to get to your nested data)
2. It takes the data structure we are querying as an *optional* second argument (of course, this would of necessity be an Object or an Array)
3. It will return the desired piece of data, which could be any type at all.

**How It Works:**

When the function is called,

- the second argument should not be defined, so that the service can reach out to the globalData object, as we will see later.
- The args Array is checked for length (`args.length ?`), and

  - if it has elements, the recursive call is made (`this.getData(`),

    - but this time, we will drop the first arg from the args Array (`args.slice(1),`),
    - and the data argument will be (re)included (`data ?`).

      - If it was defined in the most recent recursive call, then the first arg element is used to access that property(or index) on the data Object/Array (`data[args[0]] :`),
      - but if it hasn't been defined yet (like in the initial function call), the recursive call will use the globalData property instead (`this.globalData[args[0]])`).
  - As the function continues it's recursive course, the data structure is being narrowed down to deeper levels of data, and the arguments list is dwindling.

    - Once the args length resolves to false (no more args left to explore!), instead of returning another recursive call, the function simply returns the current data object (`: data ? data`).
    - In the event this function was called with an empty array, the the entire globalData will be returned (`: this.globalData`).

I hope you find this helpful, or at least enjoyable reading. I was sure excited when this solution popped in my head while showering tonight. :P

**Bonus Material**

Here is a similar (even better) approach, using ES6 rest parameters and Array.reduce (this will allow you to call the function without passing an array):

```
properties.getData = (...args) => args.reduce((data, arg) => data[arg], this.globalData)
```

call like so:

```
dataService.getData('firstarg', 'secondarg', 'onemorearg', 'desireddata')
```

**Original, dissatisfying answer:**

Since you return the data, you could simply access the property directly on the function invocation:

```
const nestedVal = dataService.getData(‘foo’).bar
```

Or:

```
const nestedVal = dataService.getData(‘foo’)[‘bar’]
```

Comment: there is this option, however I was hoping to abstract the action a bit more (just passing the whole reference to `getData` and get back what I need

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be two questions in one.

In response to your first question (passing something like `dataService.getData('foo.bar');`

You can access object properties with strings like so:

```
var property = foo['bar'];
```

You can make this recursive if you wish, example:

```
var property = foo['bar']['baz'];
```

Regarding your second question, this may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690706/recursively-looping-through-an-object-to-build-a-property-list)?

Answer (score 0):

If I might suggest using an arrow function as selector, something like:

```
dataService.getData(storage => storage.foo.bar);
```

And the function inside you service would be:

```
properties.getData = function (dataSelector) {
    return dataSelector(this.globalData);
}
```

And here is a working example:

```js
const data = {
  prop1: {
    prop2: 1
  }
};

function getData(dataSelector) {
  return dataSelector(data);
}

const prop2 = getData(data => data.prop1.prop2);

console.log(prop2);
```

Otherwise you would have to use regex to split you string, something like:

```
properties.getData = function(data) {  
  var props = data.replace(/\]/g,'').split(/\.\[/g);

 return props.reduce((obj, prop) => obj[prop], this.globalData);

}
```

For further reference [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26) article might be useful

Comment: On the arrow function selector, I am getting the error that `dataSelector` is not a function. When you pass the arrow function, is `storage.foo.bar` supposed to be stringified? Also, do you have a link to the full documentation of how this would work (with arrow functions)? I would like to fully read up on it.

Comment: @4lackof Sadly I'm on my phone so I can't make a snippet, however you could read on Arrow Functions in MDN, I'll update the answer asap

Comment: @4lackof i've updated the answer with a referencr article

Comment: @4lackof I've added a working example for the arrow function

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$parse` service:

```
  var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
  var accessor= 'a[0].b.c';

  var result = $parse(accessor)(object);
  console.log("result =>",result);

  // result => 3
```

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.run(function($parse) {

  var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
  var accessor= 'a[0].b.c';
  
  var result = $parse(accessor)(object);
  console.log("result =>",result);
  
  // result => 3 
})
```

```html
 <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
</body>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $parse Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse).