# How to get list of concatenated keys from json in typescript

Tags: json, angular

I know that there are many threads about how to get keys from json, but I didn't find my specific case. My question is a little more treaky. 
For example, consider this json:

```
 {
  "User": {
    "Username": "testuser",
    "Roles": ["Chief", "Other"],
    "Languages": ["it", "en"],
    "IsActive": true,
    "Family": {
        "Mother": "Mary",
        "Father": "Mike"
      }
  },
  "Timestamp": null
}
```

I need to get a list of all nested keys, for example:

```
User.Usernames
User.Roles
User.Languages
User.IsActive
User.Family.Mother
User.Family.Father
Timestamp
```

And not

```
User
Usernames
Roles
Languages
IsActive
Family
Mother
Father
Timestamp
```

I'm not interested to know the values of each key. I cannot search the key using the value because it can change every time.
The code:

```
Object.keys(myJson)
```

gives me only the root elements of the json (in this case "User" and "Timestamp").
I'm using typescript 2.9.2 with Angular 6.

Thank you.

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690706/recursively-looping-through-an-object-to-build-a-property-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
let obj ={
  "User": {
    "Username": "testuser",
    "Roles": ["Chief", "Other"],
    "Languages": ["it", "en"],
    "IsActive": true,
    "Family": {
        "Mother": "Mary",
        "Father": "Mike"
      }
  },
  "Timestamp": null
}

var list = [];
getProps(obj);

function getProps(obj, parent=null) {
      for (var props in obj) {

          if (typeof (obj[props]) == "object" && obj[props] !== null && !Array.isArray(obj[props]) ) {
                 getProps(obj[props],props)
          }
          else if (parent !== null) {
                  list.push(parent+"."+props);
          }
          else {
                  list.push(props);
          }
        }
    }

 console.log(list);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was searching with the key-word "json", so I didn't find that specific thread. I will try soon.

Comment: Okay, hope it will fit your expectation. It's works for 2 levels if you need to go deepier, you have to concatenate the parents before to call back the function (if condition).

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Thank you man, your solution works very well :)