# Loop over an object

Tags: javascript

I'm decoding an object and so far I got it working. Let's say I have this object:

```
var person = [{
   firstname: "Mike",
   lastname: "123&ntilde;&ntilde;&ntilde;"
   age: 20
}]
```

So in order to decode `&ntilde` and render `ñ`, I'm simply doing this:

```
new DOMParser().parseFromString(person[0].lastname, "text/html").documentElement.textContent;
```

and this will render the value

> `ñññ`

which is what I want, so it will look like this:

> lastname: "ñññ"

However, the issue that I'm facing is that I need to decode values for each property in the object because I may get those special characters for firstname or other properties. So my question is how to decode property values on an object assuming that the object may look like this:

```
var person = [{
   name: "Mike",
   lastname: "123&ntilde;&ntilde;&ntilde;"
   age: 20,
   employeer: {
     name: 'ABC Company &ntilde;&ecirc;',
     supervisors:[
         {
           name: 'Steve&auml;',
           code: '&egrave;468'
         }
     ]
   }
}]
```

**NOTE:**

I don't need help on decoding that values of each property on my object, since I'm already doing that, I just need to come up with a recursive function that will do that on a nested object

Comment: I would ask why you have such a weird object in the first place.

Comment: @melpomene they've allowed those special characters in the data Base and now they should be rendered properly on the UI.

Comment: I guess you'll need to use a recursive function which goes through all the props of the object, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690706/recursively-looping-through-an-object-to-build-a-property-list)

Comment: @G-man Yes I think I'll need like a recursive function. Any approaches?

Comment: Have you looked into using something like lodash? https://lodash.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: @AndrewBrntt Yes, I'm using lodash but not sure how to implement it :(

Comment: @Liam This is not a duplicate. Because I'm already decoding the values, but now I'm taking it to the next level where I need to decode all those values for a nested object

Comment: Yes decode === unescape, it's the same thing

Comment: another duplicate [HTML Entity Decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode)

Comment: Agree, but again I'm ALREADY unescaping OR decoding the values. I don't need help with that, but how to come up with a recursive function that will do that on each property

Comment: [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a recursive decode using DOMParser is a good idea.  Here's an in-place transformer.  Perform a deep copy first and then transform in-place if you prefer.

```js
var person = [{
   name: "Mike",
   lastname: "123&ntilde;&ntilde;&ntilde;",
   age: 20,
   employer: {
     name: 'ABC Company &ntilde;&ecirc;',
     supervisors: [
         {
           name: 'Steve&auml;',
           code: '&egrave;468'
         }
     ]
   }
}];
console.log(person);

function htmlDecode(input)
{
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
  return doc.documentElement.textContent;
}

function fix(obj) {
   for (let prop in obj) {
      switch (typeof obj[prop]) {
        case 'object':
          fix(obj[prop]);
          break;
        case 'string':
          obj[prop] = htmlDecode(obj[prop]);
          break;
      }
   }
}

fix(person);
console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

in functional languages there are libraries to recursively walk tree scructures. In clojure there is the [zipper](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.zip/zipper) and [walk](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/walk) for example.

you could write it yourself but it will quickly get complicated so I suspect using JSON.stringify + parse would give you what you need. Both functions take second argument that's `replacer` and `reviver` respectively that allow you to intercept the transformations and alter the values.

Here is example from the official documentation:

```
function replacer(key, value) {
  // Filtering out properties
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return undefined;
  }
  return value;
}

var foo = {foundation: 'Mozilla', model: 'box', week: 45, transport: 'car', month: 7};
JSON.stringify(foo, replacer);
// '{"week":45,"month":7}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function decodeObject(obj){
  if(typeof obj == 'object'){
    var text = JSON.stringify(obj),
      div = document.createElement('div');
      div.innerHTML = text;
      obj = JSON.parse(div.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  }

  return obj;
}


var person = decodeObject([{
   name: "Mike",
   lastname: "123&ntilde;&ntilde;&ntilde;",
   age: 20
}]);



console.log(person);
```