# How to apply a function on specific key value withnin the json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to apply filter on all urls within json object. Is to possible to apply a filter on specific key value in entire object?

*For Example*

```
   json ={
    "items":
        {
            "item":
                [
                    {
                        "id": "0001",
                        "url": "assets/img/abc.png",
                        "name": "Cake",
                        "ppu": 0.55,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "url": "assets/img/abc.png" },
                                        { "id": "1002", "url": "assets/img/abc.png" },
                                        { "id": "1003", "url": "assets/img/abc.png" },
                                        { "id": "1004", "url": "assets/img/abc.png" }
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5001", "url": "assets/img/abc.png" },
                                { "id": "5002", "url": "assets/img/abc.png" },
                                { "id": "5005", "url": "assets/img/abc.png" },
                                { "id": "5007", "url": "assets/img/abc.png" },
                                { "id": "5006", "url": "assets/img/abc.png" },
                                { "id": "5003", "url": "assets/img/abc.png" },
                                { "id": "5004", "url": "assets/img/abc.png" }
                            ]
                    }

                ]
        }
}
```

I want to replace all url values into file name;
assets/folder/ppp.png > ppp.png

so, result should be like,

```
    Resultjson = {
    "items":
        {
            "item":
                [
                    {
                        "id": "0001",
                        "url": "abc.png",
                        "name": "Cake",
                        "ppu": 0.55,
                        "batters":
                            {
                                "batter":
                                    [
                                        { "id": "1001", "url": "abc.png" },
                                        { "id": "1002", "url": "abc.png" },
                                        { "id": "1003", "url": "abc.png" },
                                        { "id": "1004", "url": "abc.png" }
                                    ]
                            },
                        "topping":
                            [
                                { "id": "5001", "url": "abc.png" },
                                { "id": "5002", "url": "abc.png" },
                                { "id": "5005", "url": "abc.png" },
                                { "id": "5007", "url": "abc.png" },
                                { "id": "5006", "url": "abc.png" },
                                { "id": "5003", "url": "abc.png" },
                                { "id": "5004", "url": "abc.png" }
                            ]
                    }

                ]
        }
}
```

I have tired some filters, but it doesn't apply on entire object.

Comment: Your input is invalid. Also, your output is invalid as well. Should the key always be `url`?

Comment: is url same like assets/folder/something?? and yes. @briosheje  is right.

Comment: `itm.url.replace(/assets\/folder\//, '')` Given the case url will always be same.

Comment: Also do you really have a json string you want to parse applying custom logic for `url` field,  or you actually have an object (already parsed or created somehow else)?

Comment: @briosheje I have updated the JSON input. And yes key should always be url , but value(here path) can be different

Comment: @RV no. It could be any url. I need only file name

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy no, url are not always same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming you are not using ES6, and that other solutions teach you how to change the value using maps but you need to "apply a filter on specific key value in entire object"

If you have this structure:

```
var more= [{"assets/folder/sss.png", "type": "None" },
                 {"assets/folder/ppp.png", "type": "None" }]
    ];
var formatted = more.map(function(item) {
  var formattedItem= {}
  // map every key
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    if(key !=== 'type'){
       // create a new key removing the part you don't need and assign the previous value to it
       formattedItem[key.split('/').pop()] = item[key];
    } else {
      formattedItem[key] = item[key];
    }
  });
  return formattedItem;
});
```

**Update**

Since the real json was updated, not the initial question, the problem you are trying to solve is that you need a recursive function to iterate over the tree of objects, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690706/recursively-looping-through-an-object-to-build-a-property-list):

```
function iterate(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            obj[key].forEach(function (subObj) {
                iterate(subObj);
            });
        }
        else if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
            iterate(obj[key]);
        }
        else if (key === 'url') {
            obj[key] = obj[key].split('/').pop();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: object structure can be anything.but key name `url` can be anywhere inside.

Comment: @JeetPatel I updated the answer, it shows you how to iterate recursively a tree like structure and update every single url attribute in it

Answer (score 1):

Your "json" wasn't written correctly. Also `json` is just a format, what you're working with is a javascript object/array.

Your data structure should look like this:

```
const data = [{
    "url": "assets/folder/abc.png",
    "type": "None"
  },
  {
    "url": "assets/folder/xyz.png",
    "type": "None"
  },
  {
    "more": [{
        "url":"assets/folder/sss.png",
        "type": "None"
      },
      {
        "url": "assets/folder/ppp.png",
        "type": "None"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Solution using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [Array#pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/pop)

```js
const data=[{"url":"assets/folder/abc.png","type":"None"},{"url":"assets/folder/xyz.png","type":"None"},{"more":[{"url":"assets/folder/sss.png","type":"None"},{"url":"assets/folder/ppp.png","type":"None"}]}]

function rHandler(arr){
  return arr.map(({more, url, type})=>{
     if(more){
      return {more: rHandler(more)}
     }
     
     return {url: url.split('/').pop(), type};
  });
}

const res = rHandler(data);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Input json may not be an array. and structure could be anything, not map,more and url only. I only need url, it could be anywhere inside the object

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix your input:

```
const json = [{"url": "assets/folder/abc.png", "type": "None" },
              {"url": "assets/folder/xyz.png", "type": "None" },
              {"more": [{"url": "assets/folder/sss.png", "type": "None" }],
              {"url": "assets/folder/ppp.png", "type": "None" }]
```

Then you can do smth like:

```
const formattedOutput = json.map(obj => {
  if (obj.more) {
    return {
      ...obj,
      more: obj.more.map(nestedObj => ({
        ...nestedObj,
        url: nestedObj.url.replace("assets/folder/", "")
      }))
    };
  } else {
    return { ...obj, url: obj.url.replace("assets/folder/", "") };
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks, I just updated the example json. Here in JSON `more:` can be any key or keys. I need to find value of urls and apply basename(nodejs) function to replace url with filename.