# Is it possible to select just the colored text in a .json file?

Tags: json, brackets

I'm using Brackets to edit a json file with about 1000 lines of code.
I want to extract (copy) just the text in orange... How can I do that? :)

[here's a screenshot of the .json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJBLI.png)

Comment: Please read section on [mcve]

Comment: You probably want to ask: **How do extract only the values from all key-value pairs stored within a JSON?**

Answer (score 0):

The orange text is just your text editor. Not idea what editor you're using but on Sublime I'd do a find all on ":" then select all.
Shift + Home key will select end of row (or its shift insert, I'm on a beach atm and can't exactly remember)
With that it will select everything after the ":" which you can copy and cut down from there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to extract the strings from a nested dictionary.
Leveraging [Recursively looping through an object to build a property list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690706/recursively-looping-through-an-object-to-build-a-property-list) you could do:

```
var myobject = {
    aProperty: {
        aSetting1: ["asdf","bab"]      
    },
    bProperty: {
        bSetting1: {
            bPropertySubSetting : true
        },
        bSetting2: "bString"
    },
    cProperty: {
        cSetting: "cString"
    }
}

function iterate(obj) {
        for (var property in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
                    iterate(obj[property]);
                } else if (typeof obj[property] == "string") {
                    console.log(obj[property]);                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

iterate(myobject)
```