# Output JavaScript Event Content on iOS Device

Tags: javascript, events

How can I output an Event Object or make it visible to the iOS User?

I have read that I can't stringify an Event Object. So how can the User with the iOS Device view the contents of the Event Object?

PS: A similiar functionality of `console.log` would be cool. But I can't access the console in Safari on iOS. And I only have an iOS Device so no macOS available.

Comment: are you trying to access developer tools with an iOS device? if yes, can I assume you are working on a macOS?

Comment: @caramba I have forgotten to state that I am using an iOS device. So no macOS.

Comment: Write your own console.log “replacement” then, so that you can get the info you need in text form, and display it somewhere on the page? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690706/recursively-looping-through-an-object-to-build-a-property-list should have enough hints to get you started.